# Using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart updating items w/Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, shopping-cart

I'm using https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart and all works fine but my e-commerce site is pulling data from the database dynamically. So my question is how would I edit the code below to say if another item is added to the cart then add it.

```
public function add_to_cart()
{
    $page = Pages::all();
    $input = Input::all();

    $price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $input['options']);

    if (!empty($input)) {
        $cartContents = Cart::add(array('id' => randomNumber(), 'name' => $input['product_name'], 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $price));
        $carts = Cart::content();

        $cart_session = Cart::count();
        Session::put('cart_sess', $cart_session);
    }
    return View::make('basket.cart', compact('page', 'cartContents', 'carts'));
}
```

As the above method show it adds one, but I can't seem to figure out how to add more than one item and also to add delivery to, then add it all together to the actual total a customer would pay.

Anyone else toyed around with this package and managed to get this working?

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best answer but it will do the job. I also have a different approach to your issue
In your view, make sure you have a form that covers your table plus the update all button. The "proceed to checkout" could be just a button since your cart is just a session.

```
// View (notice how the name of the qty has the rowid):
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'cart-update', 'id' => 'cart-form')) !!}
...
<td>
    <div class="cart_quantity_button">
       <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="number" name="quantity_{{ $row->rowid }}" min="1" max="10000" step="1" value="{{$row->qty}}" autocomplete="off" size="2">
    </div>
</td>
...
<button type="submit" class="btn-black pull-right" id="update_shopping">Update Shopping Cart</button>
{!! Form::close() }}

// Routes
Route::post('cart/update/', array('as' => 'cart-update', 'uses' => 'CartController@updateAll'));

// Controller
use Cart;
public function updateAll(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->all() as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($k == "_token") continue;
        $arr = explode("_", $k);
        // Update the cart -> Cart::update($rowid, $qty);
        Cart::update($arr[1], $v);
    }

    $cart = Cart::content();
    return View::make('shoppingcart', compact('cart'));

}
```

There is better way of doing this, but that should satisfy your need. Well I hope